# Sub-Quests reset in chapter 5?

Tags: bravely-default

I made it through the game all the way up until Chapter 5. I also have done all the Sub-Quests up until this point. Suddenly I noticed that ALL the blue quests had returned. Why did they all reset, what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have been following the story, you will know. Try fighting some and it should be clearer.

> The time was wound back, sort of, so the bosses all came back. And harder. But hey, new opportunities for more EXP and JP